# How i can use react hooks with native SSR (without NextJS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I make [custom SSR](https://github.com/DarkKeksik/runwith) (nodeJS, ReactJS, Webpack) and i have trouble with React hooks.
When i try use hooks for example useState (her secound arguments), i'll get error **"setGreetingsBlockData is not a function"** on server console.

```
// Code from component
const { greetingsBlockData, setGreetingsBlockData } = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
        `https://adventuretimeapi.herokuapp.com/people`,
        { method: "GET" }
    )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setGreetingsBlockData(data))
}, [])

setGreetingsBlockData({test: 1})
```

**How i can fix it?**

Comment: Should be `const [greetingsBlockData, setGreetingsBlockData] = useState({})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` returns an array, not an object

```
const [ greetingsBlockData, setGreetingsBlockData ] = useState({})
```

Comment: Ohh, i so stupid, thank